# Tabularx: Adjusting column-names to entries

Tags: tables, align, tabularx, xtable

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{scriptsize}
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{3}{D{.}{.}{6}}}
\toprule
& \mcc[1]{Col A}
& \mcc[1]{Col B} 
& \mcc[1]{Col C} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: This is model 1}}\\
\midrule
ABC  &-1.23^{***}  &-6.12   &-4.32^{*}\\
     &(-9.01)      &(-3.32) &(6.12)
\\
DEF  &-4.12        &7.01    &-0.71\\
     &(1.54)       &(0.02)  &(-1.52)

\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: This is model 2 that has a longer name than model 1}}\\
\midrule
ABC  &-0.64^*   &-0.52      &-6.01^{**}\\
     &(-1.86)   &(-7.13)    &(-9.43)   \\
DEF  &-0.23     &0.01       &-6.71  \\
     &(-0.43)   &(3.12)     &(-3.52)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The only issue I have with this table is that the column-labels are not aligned with the entries, see the markings below:

[image]

I noticed that it is because the caption `Panel B: This is model 2 that has a longer name than model 1` is long. Is there a way to keep the caption as is, but align the entries with the column-name `Col C`?

Comment: Does `\mcc[1]` do anything?  Why not just take that out?

Comment: @Teepeemm I tried, but then the columns will not be evenly spaced

Comment: you have tabularx in the title and tagged the question that way but your example does not use tabularx at all it uses the standard `tabular*`  environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to `tabularx`, you are using the standard `tabular*`.

personally I would use a `tabular` here as forcing the table to be full width just makes the columns further apart and the table harder to read (this is almost always the case for any table)

But if you you do want the table full width, you can hide the width of the spanning entries so the width is allocated equally between each column

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}

% not used \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[htp]% only use ! and h in very special "after all editing complete" emergency situations
\begin{scriptsize}
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{3}{D{.}{.}{6}}}
\toprule
& \mcc[1]{Col A}
& \mcc[1]{Col B} 
& \mcc[1]{Col C} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{4}{l}{\rlap{\textbf{Panel A: This is model 1}}}\\
\midrule
ABC  &-1.23^{***}  &-6.12   &-4.32^{*}\\
     &(-9.01)      &(-3.32) &(6.12)
\\
DEF  &-4.12        &7.01    &-0.71\\
     &(1.54)       &(0.02)  &(-1.52)

\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\rlap{\textbf{Panel B: This is model 2 that has a longer name than model 1}}}\\
\midrule
ABC  &-0.64^*   &-0.52      &-6.01^{**}\\
     &(-1.86)   &(-7.13)    &(-9.43)   \\
DEF  &-0.23     &0.01       &-6.71  \\
     &(-0.43)   &(3.12)     &(-3.52)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mclbf{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#2}}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty= ,   
         input-close-uncertainty= , 
         table-space-text-pre=(,     
         table-space-text-post=***,   
         table-format=-1.2}
    \centering
\caption{Caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l *{3}{S} }
    \toprule
    & \mcx{Col A}       &   \mcx{Col B}     
                                    &   \mcx{Col C} \\
    \midrule
\mclbf[4]{Panel A: This is model 1}                 \\
    \midrule
ABC  &  -1.23$^{***}$   &  -6.12    &  -4.32$^{*}$  \\
     & (-9.01)          & (-3.32)   &  (6.12)       \\
DEF  &  -4.12           &  7.01     &  -0.71        \\
     &  (1.54)          & (0.02)    & (-1.52)       \\
\mclbf[4]{Panel B: This is model 2 
         that has a longer name than model 1}       \\
\midrule
ABC  &  -0.64$^{*}$     &  -0.52    &  -6.01$^{**}$ \\
     & (-1.86)          & (-7.13)   & (-9.43)       \\
DEF  &  -0.23           &   0.01    &  -6.71        \\
     & (-0.43)          &  (3.12)   & (-3.52)       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]